# Can't upgrade the local fabric binaries

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, docker-image

I am trying to upgrade the local fabric binaries, because I have following error:

```
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '10' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'couchdb'
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=2.0.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.3.0
=================== WARNING ===================
  Local fabric binaries and docker images are  
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.       
===============================================
```

I deleted the fabric binaries and installed the fabric version 2.3.0. It even showed ===> `Downloading version 2.3.0 platform specific fabric binaries`
But unfortunaetly, I couldn't solve the error.

Any other suggestion what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your path of the binary in the environment variables, `echo $PATH` and verify if it is is pointing to the new binary location.

Also check your binary version like this `configtxgen --version`

Comment: Thanks. the command `configtxgen --version` cannot be found... is it normal?  What does environment variables mean in my case?

Comment: I suggest you to set the PATH for your binaries in your .bashrc file which would be pointing to your binaries.

Comment: Actually am really new in Ubuntu and Fabric. Sorry, but do you mean, that I should put my fabric samples path (home/fabric-samples) into this: `# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
 . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

Comment: something like this export PATH=$HOME/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH
at the end of file

Comment: please mark the answer accepted if it is working